# Exposing JAX-WS remote service binding in OSGi?

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, jax-ws, osgi

I have a web service that I have JAX-WS generated client bindings as below:

```
// web service client generated by JAX-WS
@WebServiceClient( ... )
public class WebService_Service extends Service {

    public WebService_Service(URL wsdlLocation, QName serviceName) {
        super(wsdlLocation, serviceName);
    }

    WebService getWebServiceSOAP() {
        // ...
    }
}

// web service interface generated by JAX-WS
@WebService( ... )
public interface WebService {
    // operation methods
}
```

I would like to expose a configured WebService_Service (WSDL location and service name) as a declarative service in OSGi. I only want this service to be exposed when an instance can be properly constructed - which requires that the WSDL (at the remote location) be accessible.

Thoughts on how to do this?

Comment: How do you detect whether the remote endpoint is available? Can you get notifications using some kind of network management agent, or are you thinking about simply polling?

Comment: Not sure. I was thinking - for this simple case, at least - that if the web service (a job cancellation service) isn't available to just continue running & ignore. -- I also opened a related question about how to expose the service clients even if the endpoint isn't accessible thus pushing the problem to consumers of the service.

Comment: So you don't know whether the Web Service on the network exists until you call it. Therefore you have to create the OSGi service that represents it basically all the time, and throw exceptions when the WS is not available. If you were able to listen to some kind of notification about the Web Service then you could register/unregister the OSGi service proxy in response.

Comment: Ok, an "always available" OSGi service representing it is a reasonable option for me. Is there a preferred way to directly expose the web service as an OSGi service?